# What is the full path files are saved to on Word for Mac?

Tags: ms-office

I clicked on saving locally and then hit CMD-G to be able to change the directory. The save dialog does not say where it is saving to. If I put  it in myself I will end up with at least two differnt copies:

[image]

How can the full path be viewed ?

Comment: Under the "where" field, there's an arrow button (pointed down).  What do you see?

Comment: @Allan  Ok _now_ it shows the correct location.  It did not before

Comment: Keep note as to when it does this again.  Maybe we can figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now see the correct directory, but only after finding it manually via searches on the hard disk.

The problem appears to have surfaced since for some reason Word loses track of where the file had already been saved. I'm not sure how it happened since I already had saved a local copy using Word. Maybe due to one of those (frequent) auto-updates?

A commenter @Allan asked about what is under the arrow button - and before it had a set of irrelevant directories. I set the location manually and now Word does remember it.

[image]